# LINQ Out of Memory Error

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework, system.reactive

I am querying 200k records and using up all the server's memory (no surprise). I am new to LINQ so I found the following code that should help me but I don't know how to use it:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int batchSize)
{
    List<T> nextbatch = new List<T>(batchSize);
    foreach (T item in collection)
    {
        nextbatch.Add(item);
        if (nextbatch.Count == batchSize)
        {
            yield return nextbatch;
            nextbatch = new List<T>(batchSize);
        }
    }
    if (nextbatch.Count > 0)
        yield return nextbatch;
}
```

Source: http://goo.gl/aQZIj

Here is my code which creates the "out of memory" error. How do I incorporate the new Batch function into my code?

```
var crmMetrics = _crmDbContext.tpm_metricsSet.Where(a => a.ModifiedOn >= lastRunDate);

foreach (var crmMetric in crmMetrics)
{
    metric = new Metric();                                
    metric.ProductKey = crmMetric.tpm_Product.Id;
    dbContext.Metrics.Add(metric);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Do you need SaveChanges inside the loop?

Comment: Good point. Can I add 200k objects before saving? Linq is new to me.

Comment: 200k just sounds like it is much, but it depends on the objects and of course your server. Given 4 GB of memory and objects that have 10 KB size...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an extension method, so if it is part of a static class and there is a reference to the class's namespace in your code you could do:

```
var crmMetricsBatches = _crmDbContext.tpm_metricsSet
                        .Where(a => a.ModifiedOn >= lastRunDate)
                        .AsEnumerable() // !!
                        .Batch(20);
```

Except it wouldn't help. By the `.AsEnumerable()`, you still fetch all data in memory but now in chunks of 20. This is because you can't use the method directly against `IQueryable`: Entity Framework will try to translate it to SQL but of course has no clue how to do that.

As said by TGH, `Skip` and `Take` are more made for this:

```
var crmMetricsPage = _crmDbContext.tpm_metricsSet
                        .Where(a => a.ModifiedOn >= lastRunDate)
                        .OrderBy(a => a.??) // some property you choose
                        .Skip(pageNo * pageSize)
                        .Take(pageSize);
```

where `pageNo` counts from `0` to the number of pages (`- 1`) you're going to need. `Skip` and `Take` are *expressions*, and EF knows how to convert these to SQL. The `OrderBy` is required for EF to know where to start skipping.

In this process, called *paging*, you always get `pageSize` records at a time. The number of queries is greater, but resources are spared. One condition is that you can determine a `pageSize` in advance. I don't know if this fits with your logic.

If you can't use paging you should try to narrow the filter (`Where(a => a.ModifiedOn >= lastRunDate`), e.g. try to get the data in batches of one day or week.

Comment: Thanks. This method has fixed the memory issue but it's been running for 12 hours and is only at 45,000 records. Any thoughts on speeding it up?

Comment: WHAT? What was the page size? Are there indexes on the sorted column you and `ModifiedOn`? And what database (+ version) do you work with?

Comment: I changed the pageSize from 5000 to 500 which has sped up the process considerably.

Comment: Now I notice that you should also do the saving in batches and use a _new context_ for each batch.

Comment: Wow... Much faster! I understand the benefit of saving in batches but how is the new context helping?

Comment: The context caches all objects you attach to it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Linq's Skip and Take to get the batches

Check this out:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/take-and-skip-operator-in-linq-to-sql/